# Workaround for "Hey Google" not playing a chime

Tags: accessibility, motorola, google-assistant

When I say "Hey google", I no longer hear a chime (since some recent-ish update). Lots of places online suggest to turn on the Switch Access accessibility feature, which would supposedly fix the bug (supposing it's a bug). But my Moto G62 5G doesn't have the "Switch Access" feature.

Then I had the idea to use a macro app such as MacroDroid to intercept the "Hey Google" and react with a chime, but I didn't find that sort of trigger - neither in MacroDroid nor in Tasker.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Switch Access accessibility app can be downloaded from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.accessibility.switchaccess), though I'm curious if it's the solution. If it is, then feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks! I installed that, but it didn't fix my "missing chime" problem unfortunately.